Converting WAV to MIDI using online AI
I have some WAV files that I'd like to convert into notes.
The tool should

be able to deal with multiple instruments, not only one
separate the voice

speech recognition is not needed (Speech to text)
the melody of the voice should be transcribed to notes


output a MIDI file
cost

less than ~10USD/month at a monthly subscription
~1 USB per file


asks for payment details after the free trial period, not right from the start

I have tried:

WavTool, but they want me to enter payment credentials right from the beginning. And their Indie-Plan does not allow converting WAV to MIDI. "Export as MIDI" just allows you to save a MIDI file from online to hard disk.


I have my serious doubts you can find good software for this. Just sample example: to distinguish which instrument play specific note (this is fixed, more or less, frequency) you need to investigate the harmonics. But different specimens of particular instrument will have (IMHO) different harmonic characteristics. And you can reach a situation when on the same time some other instrument (or voice) "play" the same (harmonic) frequency.

@RomeoNinov: I know that this is a hard task. But AI has advanced quite a bit. Certainly it will not work for an orchestra with 60 people, but it might do for a band with 3 people (drums, bass, keyboard and vocals).
